# PHP call generates a UL. I don't know how to get three li elements into that UL

Tags: php, html-lists

I'm trying to put the social media icons on the same line of the page as the WP menu. The menu is being called by one PHP call and the icons are being called by another. This puts them is separate ULs. How do I get them in the same UL so they appear on the same line on my page? This is the code: The link to the page is www.trailtrainer.net

```
<!-- The Navigation Menu -->
<ul id="navi">
<h1 id="fittext3"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a><i><?php bloginfo('description');?></i></h1>
<ul id="fittext1" style="width: 100%;><?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'bar' ) ) :  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'bar', 'depth' => 2 ) ); else : ?>
<?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&depth=2' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( ( get_theme_mod('facebook_setting') != 'The url link goes in here.' ) && ( get_theme_mod('facebook_setting') != '' ) ) : ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod('facebook_setting') ;?>" class="icon-facebook-rect"></a></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( ( get_theme_mod('twitter_setting') != 'The url link goes in here.' ) && ( get_theme_mod('twitter_setting') != '' ) ) : ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod('twitter_setting') ;?>" class="icon-twitter"></a></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( ( get_theme_mod('youtube_setting') != 'The url link goes in here.' ) && ( get_theme_mod('youtube_setting') != '' ) ) : ?><li><a href="<?php echo     get_theme_mod('youtube_setting') ;?>" class="icon-youtube"></a></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- End Navigation Menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, quick and dirty, but I this should be in the ballpark of what you're looking for:

```
<?
function settingExists($name)
{
    return ((get_theme_mod($name) != 'The url link goes in here') && get_theme_mod($name) != ''));
}

if(settingExists('facebook_setting') || settingExists('twitter_setting') || settingExists('youtube_setting'))
{
    echo("<li>");
    if(settingExists('facebook_setting')){
        echo("<a href="get_theme_mod('facebook_setting')>" class="icon-facebook-rect"></a><)";
    }
    if(settingExists('twitter_setting')){
        echo("<a href="get_theme_mod('twitter_setting')>" class="icon-facebook-rect"></a><)";
    }

    if(settingExists('youtube_setting')){
        echo("<a href="get_theme_mod('youtube_setting')>" class="icon-facebook-rect"></a><)";
    }
    echo("</li>");

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry, I'm not great at reading between the lines when it comes to code. Do you mind showing me what that bit of code would look like if it were put into my .php file? I added more code to the original post for more details.